# Why Can't I Populate an Array inside a method declaration in C#?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core

I am writing an application where I need to read a set of JSON files and create objects from a model in my application. This doesn't seem all that difficult and the code looks right to me, but I am using an array to store the JSON strings, and for some reason Visual Studio is red underlining the array name and saying it's an "unassigned local variable", even though I declare it before the foreach loop.

I'm somewhat of a novice in C#, so if someone could let me know how to correct this I would greatly appreciate it.

The line in question starts with "lotRanges[i] = JsonConvert..."

```
namespace InternalReceiptImport.Services
{
    interface ILotRangeService
    {
        List<LotRange> GetAll();
    }
    public class LotRangeService : ILotRangeService
    {
        public List<LotRange> GetAll()
        {
            string jsonFilePath = @"\Data";
            Array files = Directory.GetFiles(jsonFilePath);
            LotRange[] lotRanges;

            int i = 0;
            foreach (string filename in files)
            {
                string filepath = jsonFilePath + "\\" + filename;
                string json = File.ReadAllText(filepath);
                lotRanges[i] = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LotRange>(json);
                i++;
            }

            List<LotRange> listLotRanges = lotRanges.ToList();
            return listLotRanges;
        }
    }
}
```

It was suggested below I just use a list instead of an array. I tried that, but it's giving me the same error on the line I am using to add to the list. Here is the code...

```
namespace InternalReceiptImport.Services
{
    interface ILotRangeService
    {
        List<LotRange> GetAll();
    }
    public class LotRangeService : ILotRangeService
    {
        public List<LotRange> GetAll()
        {
            string jsonFilePath = @"\Data";
            Array files = Directory.GetFiles(jsonFilePath);
            List<LotRange> listLotRanges;

            int i = 0;
            foreach (string filename in files)
            {
                string filepath = jsonFilePath + "\\" + filename;
                string json = File.ReadAllText(filepath);
                listLotRanges.Add(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LotRange>(json));
                i++;
            }

            return listLotRanges;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `lotRanges` has been *declared* but has not been *assigned*. Assigning requires something on the right side of an equals sign.

Comment: sorry if this sounds obtuse, but isn't that what the line in question is doing? Assigning it? This is how you would assign a value to an array in every other programming language I have used, but it doesn't work in C#?

Comment: You declare it, but you don't assign it with a value. But there are several issues with your code: 1) don't use `Array files`. Directory.GetFiles returns a `string[]`. If you don't want to spell it out just write `var files = Directory.GetFiles(jsonFilePath)`. 2. You would need to assign lotRanges with a value, i.e. LotRange[] lotRanges = new LotRange[input-length-of-array-here]`. 3) If you don't know the length beforehand, use a list instead of an array. 4) If you convert your `lotRanges` array to a `listLotRanges` list anyway why not work with the list directly?

Comment: @Carl No, you don't assign anything. You assign `jsonFilePath`, `files`, `i` and `listLotRanges` (in your first snippet), but `lotRanges` is missing an assigning which you easily see in that there is no `=` sign.

Comment: `lotRanges[i] = ...` would assign a value to an element of the array at index `i`, if `lotRanges` was something. But it's not, since you've not assigned the variable to anything. Basically `LotRange[] lotRanges;` tells the compiler, "I'm going to want an array of `LotRange` objects, and I want to use the name `lotRanges` to refer to it. Get ready." So the compiler reserves the name `lotRanges` and makes sure the only thing that can go in there is an array of `LotRange` objects. But it still needs that array of `LotRange` objects to be there before it will let you access any of the indices.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Ok, makes sense. If you look above I have changed it to a list, but still had the same problem. I will leave it there so this post might help someone in the future, but the fix was assigning the list to "new List<LotRange>();"

Comment: @HereticMokey Noting your comment above that GetFiles returns a string, any advice in how to turn that to a list or an array since I need to iterate through the filenames to read them and get the JSON out of them?

Comment: `List<LotRange> listLotRanges = new List<LotRange>();` You must initialize `listLotRanges`. In C#, just declaring the variable `listLotRanges` doesn't create anything but a reference that *could* refer to an existing list object -- but not until you, the programmer, create the list and assign it. When it was an array, you had the same problem: It was a reference that didn't refer to anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in both your examples the problem is that `lotRanges` is declared but it has not been assigned a value yet, that is, it is `null`. In order to fix this, all you have to do is assign a value to your declared variable. In the array case, you have to define the size of it upfront:

```cs
Array files = Directory.GetFiles(jsonFilePath);
LotRange[] lotRanges = new LotRange[files.Length];
```

And in the case of using a `List<LotRange>` you don't need to know the size upfront, which is one of the reasons why people tend to prefer using `List<T>` for scenarios like this.

```cs
List<LotRange> lotRanges = new List<LotRange>();
```